# Is it correct and natural to ask "do you have length and width" when you want to know if the person knows the dimensions of something?

Tags: word-usage, questions

Would you tell me if it is correct and natural to ask *do you have length and width* when you want to know if the person knows the dimensions of something? For example:

> You said the fridge's height is 50 inches. Do you have **length** and **width** besides height?

If it doesn't sound natural, how would you phrase the question?

Comment: It's almost OK, but you need definite articles: "You said the fridge's height is 50 inches. Do you have **the** length and width besides **the** height?"

Comment: (You wouldn't want to suggest that the person you're asking is one-dimensional, would you? ;) By the way, "Is [this phrase] correct and natural" isn't always a useful question. Sometimes an "incorrect" usage is so common that the correct one can sound stilted in informal settings. "What is correct" and "what sounds appropriate for my setting" can be two different questions, unless you're in a formal academic setting.

Comment: Length and width are generally easy to measure. But, the length and width of my refrigerator are hard to measure.

Comment: And for a refrigerator, I'd probably use *depth* rather than *length*.